# Limiting values calculated and returned by Apache Solr Statscomponent

Tags: apache, solr, statistics

Is there a way to configure solr statscomponent http://bit.ly/T4PLnl to NOT include the "expensive" sumOfSquares and stddev ?

We only need sum, min,max,mean,count and missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [AnalyticsComponent](http://www.slideshare.net/SHIEngineers/whats-new-in-apache-solr-47-und-elasticsearch-11), which supports the following:

- All functionality of StatsComponent ([SOLR-4499](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4499))
- Field Faceting ([SOLR-3435](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3435))
- Support for limit
- Sorting (bucket name or any stat in the bucket
- Support for offset
- Range Faceting
- Supports all options of standard range faceting
- Query Faceting ([SOLR-2925](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2925))
- Ability to use overall/field facet statistics as input to range/query faceting (ie calc min/max date and then facet over that range
- Support for more complex aggregate/mapping operations ([SOLR-1622](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1622))
- Aggregations: min, max, sum, sum-of-square, count, missing, stddev, mean, median, percentiles
- Operations: negation, abs, add, multiply, divide, power, log, date math, string reversal, string concat

Usage:

```
Turning it on
Parameter Default Description
olap=[true/false] Enable enhanced analytics functionality
```

**References**

- [SOLR-5302: Analytics Component](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5302)
- [Search Analytics Component Guide (pdf)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12606793/Search%20Analytics%20Component.pdf)
- [Solr Source: AnalyticsParams.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/contrib/analytics/src/java/org/apache/solr/analytics/util/AnalyticsParams.java)
- [Next-generation search and analytics with Apache Lucene and Solr 4](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-solr-lucene/)
- [RequestHandlers and SearchComponents in SolrConfig](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig)
- [Search Analytics Component: Presented by Steven Bower, Bloomberg L.P.](http://www.slideshare.net/lucidworks/search-analytics-component-presented-by-steven-bower-bloomberg-lp)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain _how_ to use it?  After an hour of fiddling, I finally got it to appear when I include `olap=true` in the query (two requirements in solrconfig.xml are undocumented), but even then, the PDFs in the SOLR-5302 ticket are the only documentation I could find - and the `fieldfacet` option doesn't work.

Comment: @Izkata Did you have to install this? I tried setting olap=true and other parameters, but it does nothing. You mention changing the solrconig.xml. Can you point me to what you changed. This component would be a lifesaver for me if it works.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites Solr 5.0, I didn't have to install anything.  Unfortunately I didn't keep what I added, but I remember adding another `<searchComponent>` and something inside `<requestHandler>` in solrconfig.xml

Comment: @Izkata I got this working over the weekend and it seems to do everything I need for the most part. :)

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites Can you write up an answer on how to correctly use it, then?

Comment: I'll see about writing one up here soon. But, it's basically what you said... adding the component to the solrconfig. You also have to set docValues=true on the field you are grouping by. I still haven't figured out how to do a district count yet, but it handles the rest nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I tried once. All I cared about was sum, count, and missing, and still profiling showed that the stats are so cheap to compute as to be free. Consider that sumOfSquares requires O(1) space and O(n) time, the same as sum, min, max, mean, count, and missing. Whether you compute sumOfSquares or not, StatsComponent still has to iterate over the result set and fetch the field value for each doc. ParseDouble is overwhelmingly the hotspot for non-faceted stats, at least if you're using a string field!